# Apache Flink error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.table.sources.TableSource?

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am writing a streaming service in Apache Flink. I am basically picking data from a CSV file by using org.apache.flink.table.sources.CsvTableSource. 
Below is the code for same:

```
 StreamTableEnvironment streamTableEnvironment = TableEnvironment
                .getTableEnvironment(streamExecutionEnvironment);

    CsvTableSource csvTableSource = CsvTableSource.builder().path(pathToCsvFile)
            .field("XXX0", Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP).field("XXX1", Types.INT)
            .field("XXX2", Types.DECIMAL).field("XXX3", Types.INT).field("XXX4", Types.INT)
            .field("XXX9", Types.DECIMAL).field("XXX5", Types.STRING)
            .field("XXX6", Types.STRING).field("XXX7", Types.STRING).fieldDelimiter(",").lineDelimiter("\n")
            .ignoreFirstLine().ignoreParseErrors().build();

    streamTableEnvironment.registerTableSource("metrics_table", csvTableSource);

    Table selectedMetricTable = streamTableEnvironment.sqlQuery(getSQLQuery(metricsType, metricsGroupingLevel));

    DataStream<Tuple2<Boolean, MetricsTimeSeriesData>> metricStream = streamTableEnvironment
            .toRetractStream(selectedMetricTable, MetricsTimeSeriesData.class);
```

But its giving following error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.table.sources.TableSource
```

Here are the maven dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-scala_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I can see the source defination of the above class, still I am getting this error. Please Help?

Answer (score 1):

The module `flink-table` is not shipped with the flink binary distribution, therefore it is not shipped to the cluster by default. You can either put that dependency to your cluster installation (in `\lib` folder) see the last section of [setup](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/table/#setup) or you can submit your job as uber-jar with that dependency packaged, see [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/start/dependencies.html#appendix-template-for-bulding-a-jar-with-dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Flink 1.8.0 version, I was facing the same issue. I able to fix it by adding below dependency in **pom.xml** by pointing to **flink-table_2.12-1.8.0.jar** from my system path.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>E:\flink-1.8.0-scala_2.12\opt\flink-table_2.12-1.8.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

Hope it will help you.